# Pip - No module named vimpdb

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pip

I'm trying to install the vimpdb lib but it's working, even though I successfully installed vimpdb using pip install I always get this error:

```
import vimpdb; vimpdb.set_trace();
ImportError: No module named vimpdb
```

I'm running the code locally  but when I run the same code as a simple script (without using localhost) it imports correctly, it only throws an error when I start a server and begin to try using this plugin.

Any ideas?

Thansk!

Comment: Does your server have permission to import the file? What do your permissions looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine won't import Python modules on your Python path.  You need to actually include the module within the App Engine project.

For example, in the same directory as `app.yaml`, you could add a symbolic link similar to this:

```
vimpdb -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vimpdb
```

Or you could copy the `vimpdb` directory to that location.

Comment: Creating a symlink to your system Python's `vimpdb` will allow the development server to find it, but the import is likely to raise an AttributeError when `vimpdb` tries to access `subprocess.Popen`. I'm guessing this is due to the related App Engine sandbox limitation.